# Should a REST API server received JSON data or a normal form data with PUT?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I am building an REST API server with **Node.js** and **jQuery** with **HTML5**,

and there's some routes like

`PUT /profile`, `PUT /settings` to change the profile datas or the user settings,

but I don't know what type of the data should I send to the REST API server,

should I just send a normal form data like how we send a `POST` to the server (when the method is `PUT`)

or should I change the form data to json, and send a `application/json` via the AJAX?

Comment: def JSON, if you have an api that means people will get stuff from it too right? you should use JSON for both, google RESTful API design, its not required, but you did ask under a JS tag

Answer (score 1):

both methods will work fine for you so it all comes down to a matter of personal preference.
it's important that you are consistent across all of your APIs.
personally i'm always using JSON with application/json
IMHO, it's more readable.

Comment: So did you always `JSON.stringify()` the form data?

Comment: it's up to you how you decide to create the JSON.  BTW, another advantage of using this format would be the ease your server side code would be able to parse it.

Comment: I did not use JSON.stringify in places where I wanted control over the form data.  For example, removing or manipulating a field before creating the JSON.